# UIPageViewController inside of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

Hey I wanted to ask how do I implement a UIPageViewController inside of a UITableViewCell.

I have been reading around, but so far nothing seems to work for anyone trying.

I would appreciate some hints, no need for a full answer..

Thanks!.

Comment: you probably need to add UIPageControl to add as a subview on you cell ?

Answer (score 6):

It is unclear exactly what you are attempting to do, but let me see if I can explain. You want to have a page view controller view inside a table view cell.

You will need to create a page view controller per cell, resize its view to the size of the cell's content view and add the view as a subview of the cell. You will then have to implement the page view controller's datasource and delegate methods inside the cell.

Something like:

```
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
[self.pageViewController setDataSouce:self];
[self.pageViewController setDelegate:self];
[self.pageViewController.view setFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
self.contentView addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
```

However, this is a peculiar design, which looks over-complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I think I am starting to get the idea of how to use the PageController. I realize how this might make it seem like I am making something really complicated but no worries.

Comment: Maybe he's trying to do a Facebook style swipe left and right gallery from within a tableview? Who knows what he's trying to do but I don't think we can say it's "over" complicated.