# How to implement UIPageViewController inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a slideshow inside 'UITableViewCell'. So, I need to use 'UIPageViewController' to make the slideshow. I have tried to implement a solution here [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711360/uipageviewcontroller-inside-of-a-uitableviewcell) but I can't add UIPageViewController to UITableViewCell content view.

This is my code in UITableViewCell

```
let slideshowPageViewController = SlideshowPageViewController()
self.addSubview(slideshowPageViewController)
```

> Error : Cannot convert value of type 'UIPageViewController' to
>   expected argument type 'UIView'

Can anyone advice another solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend this. UIPageViewController, well, is a UIViewController. I've always found it way too complex for any real-world use — especially if you just need to cycle through images for a slide show.

I would recommend adding a child UIScrollView to the UITableViewCell and handling the slideshow code yourself.

[Here is a code sample](https://github.com/rosem/code-samples/blob/master/SimpleAppInstructions/IntroViewController.swift) with a few good practices when setting up a UIScrollView. The most important part being calculating the current index in scrollViewDidScroll delegate call:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Calculate current index
    let index =  Int(round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width))
    updateCurrentIndex(index: index)
}
```

If you need to scroll the slideshow for the user, do not call updateCurrentIndex directly. Instead, call setContentOffset, the delegate will still fire and you're updateCurrentIndex method will work just as if the user is manually scrolling.

```
@IBAction func didNext() {
    if (currentIndex < scrollView.subviews.count-1) {
        let point = CGPoint(x: scrollView.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(currentIndex + 1), y: 0)
        scrollView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTermsSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution but the problem is I want to make the cycling image. Can I implement UIScrollView with infinity loop?

Comment: Do you want to go back to page one and start over, or will it always look like it's moving to new pages (left to right)? Will you allow user-interaction (allow the user to cycle images), or do you want to cycle through images automatically? Either way, I don't think UIPageViewController allows infinite looping out of the box.

Comment: I want to cycle through images automatically and user can also swipe to change slideshow image. (like a carousel)

Comment: That's a bit more work, but I would still use UIScrollView. You'll have three (left, center, right) content views inside it. When the index changes you'll need to reposition and reload your content views.

Answer (score 0):

I work hard to find the solution. And, I have already found that.

In rowAtIndexPath, I add childViewController and it works for me.

```
let slideshowPageViewController = SlideshowPageViewController()
self.addChildViewController(slideshowPageViewController)
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Slideshow", for: indexPath)

cell.contentView.addSubview(slideshowPageViewController.view)
```

Hopefully, this can help anyone who has the same problem.